# Hiding user data from developers

Tags: privacy

We have an online store with a reasonable amount of subscribers.

We are thinking about creating development and staging environments for the new features/changes. Since these new environments will be created using a copy from the Production environment they'll contain user data, and we don't want that information to be available to the developers.

What is the best way to go about it?

Below are the plugins that are used by the store that may have store user information.

- WooCommerce
- LearnDash

The data we want to obscure or delete is

- Email address
- User name (first name, last name, display name)
- contact information (address, phone number, billing address, etc.)
- Orders
- Social media URLs
- Uploads

Comment: Why don't you just replace these fields with random data before you hand the database copy to the devs?

Comment: @fuxia is right, the only way really is to give the developers dummy data.

Comment: That's indeed what I've been thinking about doing. I was wondering if there were standard procedures/best practices followed by the community.